# Google Maps not working on iPhone/iPad worklight 6.2 app

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-runtime

I am developing an app for my organization which require to show its office location on Map, when user clicks on the link app will open google map on browser and display the route between user current location and the selected office marker. This is perfectly working fine in Android App but not working on iPhone/iPad apps. I am using below code:

I have declared the google api script in index.html file

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;sensor=false"></script>
```

below is the code for location.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport"   content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
</head>
<body style="display: none; background-color: silver; color: green; font-size: small;">


    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <div data-role="content" id="contentMap">
                <div id="map_canvas" style="position: absolute !important; top: 10px !important; right: 0; bottom: 5px !important; left: 0 !important;"></div>
            </div>
    </div>
<script src="js/location.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

below is the code for location.js file:

```
/* JavaScript content from js/location.js in folder common */
function OfficeLocation(latitude,longitude,name,address){
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.longitude = longitude;
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
}

var officeLocationArray = [
                            new OfficeLocation(32.3947198, -90.1457959, "office location 1", "office location 1"),
                            new OfficeLocation(31.7138728, -89.1492813, "office location 1", "office location 1"),
                            new OfficeLocation(32.2777552, -90.1223944, 'office location 1', 'office location 1')
                          ];

// would be used as users current location
var usersLat;
var usersLng;
var youAreHereMarkers; //markers to represent current user location ( blue marker is used). can replace with any image or gifs ( like blue dot gifs)
var map; //
var mapURL; //users location and destination selected by user are stored in this variablse in order to use it to open google map in new browser with route visible
var currentPosition; // will store lat/lng location for google map api. 
var infowindow; //displays information about the location when user clicks marker on map
/**
 * everthing happens here 
 * 
 * on success : getuser location,get new map , add user markers, add win job markers , add marker listeners  that lets you open original google map with direction
 * on failure: get new map, add all winjob marker 
 */
$("#divLocation").on("pageshow", function(event, ui) {
    alert("map initiliaziation started");
    getUsersCurrentLocationAndPopulateMap();
});

/**
 * 
 */
function getUsersCurrentLocationAndPopulateMap() {
    var options = {
              enableHighAccuracy: true,
              timeout: 10000,
              maximumAge: 0
            };
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(locationFound, locationNotFound, options);
}

/**
 * creates new map, and adds all marker related information
 * @param pos
 */
function locationFound(pos){
    try{
        var coords = pos.coords;
        usersLat = coords.latitude;//pos.coords.latitude;
        usersLng = coords.longitude;//pos.coords.longitude;
        getNewMap();
        addUsersLocationMarker();
        addAllMarkers();
    }catch (e) {
        alert(e.message);
    }
}

/**
 * user location is not determined.
 * possible gps sensor problem
 * @param err
 */
function locationNotFound(err){
    showAlert("Unable to determine your location.");
    getNewMap();
    addAllMarkers();
    alert('ERROR(' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);

}
/**
 * new map is created
 */
function getNewMap() {
    try{
        var zoomlevel = 7;
        var usersLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(usersLat, usersLng);
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
            zoom : zoomlevel,
            center : usersLocation,
            mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
    }catch(e){
        alert(e.message);
    }
}

/**
 * place users locatin markers on map and also all win job locations markers
 * based on array provided
 */
function addUsersLocationMarker(){
    try{
        var blueMarker = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
                'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png',
                new google.maps.Size(37, 34), new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                new google.maps.Point(0, 19));
        //placing users location map
        //http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png
        youAreHereMarkers = new google.maps.Marker({
            position : new google.maps.LatLng(usersLat, usersLng),
            map : map,
            animation : google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
            title : "You are Here",
            icon : blueMarker//'images/here.png'
        });
    }catch (e) {
        alert(e.message);
    }
}

/**
 * reads all the marker informatin from officeLocationArray and place it on the map as clickable markers
 */
function addAllMarkers() {
    //clickable region
    var shape = {
        coord : [ 1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18, 1 ],
        type : 'poly'
    };

    // populalte markers on all WIN Job Center location
    var numberOfLocations = officeLocationArray.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfLocations; i++) {
        var ofcLocation = officeLocationArray[i];

        var flag = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
                'http://googlemaps.googlermania.com/google_maps_api_v3/en/Google_Maps_Marker.png',
                new google.maps.Size(37, 34), new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                new google.maps.Point(0, 19));
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(ofcLocation.latitude), parseFloat(ofcLocation.longitude));
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position : myLatLng,
            map : map,
            icon : flag,
            shape : shape,
            title : ofcLocation.name + "\n" + ofcLocation.address
        });

        //  listens if user clicks on marker to display infowindow, and eventually driving to google map in new browser
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function() {
            try{
                if(infowindow){
                    infowindow.close();
                }
                map.setZoom(8);
                map.setCenter(marker.position);
                var destinationAddress = this.getTitle().split("\n");
                mapURL = "http://www.google.com/maps/dir/'"+ usersLat + "," + usersLng + "'/'"+ destinationAddress[0]+","+ destinationAddress[1] + "'";
                var contentString=destinationAddress[0]+ /*"<br />"+ destinationAddress[1]+*/ "<br/><div><a href='#' onClick='openGoogMap()' > Go to this location </a></div>";
                infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    maxWidth: 200,
                    content : "<div style='overflow:hidden;line-height:1.35;min-width:200px;'>"+contentString+"</div>"
                });

                infowindow.open(map, this);
                //  showAlert(openMapString);
            }catch (e) {
                alert(e.message);
            }
        });
    }
}
/**
 * opens google map in a browser with information appended in mapURL
 */
function openGoogMap() {
    WL.App.openURL(mapURL);
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Worklight Version : 6.2.0.0

Xcode Version : 6

Comment: If you say "browser", why all the code? Do you want to open the OS's EXTERNAL BROWSER APP or display the map IN YOUR APP?

Comment: Looks like you are having same issue as described in this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26968505/google-map-with-co-ordinates-not-showing). Add your Google maps API key to the JS src link.

Comment: where is `#divLocation` page? wrap `.ui-content` in `data-role="page"` with id `divLocation` and amend your JS `$(document).on("pageshow", "#divLocation", function () { /* init map */ });`

Comment: @IdanAdar I want to open maps inside the app and when used clicks on particular marker then I am redirecting user to OS External Browser App.

Comment: @learningloop I have included API Key in the script element, its still now working on iPad. I have checked it in chrome/FF/safari and its working fine everywhere except inside App.

Comment: @Omar "#divLocation page" is in index. html file. the code is working fine in browsers and Android app. Its just not working in iPad/iPhone. "navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition" always calling locationNotFound method when I open page on iPad app.

Comment: @PrerakTiwari I just ran your code and I was able to see the 3 "2 in Jackson, MS and 1 in Laurel, MS" markers you are placing on the map. I'm using iOS emulator for iPad Air iOS 8.1. What I found was that the height of the html and and body elements in your location.html file was not set, at least in the code you posted, so I set it to 100% and I was able to see the map with the markers.

Comment: I have uploaded my code at following location https://www.dropbox.com/s/f2ugx8hry7htpot/LocationTest%202.zip?dl=0 I tried changing height and width to 100% also but its not working. After page load it always giving me error "ERROR(3) : Position Retrieval Timeout".

Comment: @Omar did you find something fishy in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey. Got the answer. Since I was building my app in XCode 6 and using worklight version 6.2.0.0, that's why this piece of code creating problems. You can read about the issue from [IBM Website](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI25756). To solve this issue download the following [fix pack](http://www-933.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/selectFixes?parent=ibm~Other%2Bs%2Foftware&product=ibm/Other%20software/IBM%20Worklight%20Consumer%20Edition&release=6.2.0/.0&platform=All&function=fixId&fixids=6.2.0-WCE-FP0001&includeSupersedes=0) which will update your worklight version to 6.2.0.1. After doing that, you have to add following entry in **pathToYourProject\YourProject\apps\yourAppName\iphone\native\yourAppName-Info.plist** file:

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Permissions Message for App even when not in use</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Permissions Message for App when in use</string>
```

Build and Redeploy your app, it should work fine now.