# Google map with co-ordinates not showing

Tags: css, html, google-maps

I am trying to get a google map to show on my site but it's not. I successfully import the required JS file:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
```

I also got an external JS file with the necessary code imported correctly. It's contents are:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  console.log('document ready');
  function initializeMap() {
    console.log('initialize');
    var myOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        myOptions);
  }
  initializeMap();
});
```

My HTML looks something like (I am using bootstrap3 for my styles):

```
<div class="container" style="height:100%; width: 100%;">
        <div style="height:100%; width: 100%;">
                <div id="map-canvas">

                </div>
            </div>
</div
```

But the map doesn't show. However, if I place the code below into the div map-canvas, a map shows

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d3988.7878538147397!2d36.828219000000004!3d-1.3022289999999999!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x182f111cdbaa9205%3A0xe6a1c22d75cae422!2sAfcon+Limited!5e0!3m2!1sen!2s!4v1416212583057" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is CSS-related, you aren't setting `height` and `width` of elements correctly. It work on `iframe` because you have specified `height` and `width`.

Usage of *percentage* in `height` is tricky, so you should set it to `html` and `body`, and then let child elements `inherit` `body`'s `height`. This will fit any screen resolution.

Easy option, be specific and use `px`, `em`, etc, instead of *percentage*.

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container,
.container > div,
.container > div #map-canvas {
  height: inherit;
}
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/fssr019x/)**

Answer (score 0):

Have you got your API key ?

[Check here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key)

Try with [this code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#HelloWorld)

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY">
</script>
```